# Best Ways to combine two Pandas Dataframes Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames (for now) that I want to combine:

```
                head_site_df = pd.DataFrame(head_sitetupaggr_list, columns =['Die Loc', 'X Coord', 'Y Coord'])
                regvalfile_df = pd.DataFrame(regvaltupaggr_list)
```

regvalfile_df contains more than 800 columns that are generated dynimcally. So I cannot list the columns out.
Why I say for now is because the situation is a little complicated. I need to produce an excel sheet that looks like this:

[image]

This data comes from a log file. After column K, you can have 800 or more columns with those headers with integer values. These are the columns contained in regvalfile_df. The other DF captures columns 'Die Loc' and 'X Coord', 'Y Coord'. I intend to modify my code to be able to eventually have this second DF also capture columns A to K. So in total, I will have two DFs. One which has A to K and another which has L and onwards.

My question is, in order to combine these two seperate DFs to get the excel sheet, what is the best method to use. Cocatenate(), Merge)(), Join(), or Append()? What is the most efficient method with speed and mem consumption. I'd be combining two pandas DFs. Unless it'd be more efficient to somehow have one DF capture everything. I don't see how it would work given that L onwards has "dynamic" amount headers that change for each file.

Sample of code so far. Please note the code works. I just took out a huge chunk out that contain datastructures I have used so far:

```
    for odfslogp_obj in odfslogs_plist:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(odfslogp_obj, mode='r') as z:
        for name in z.namelist():
            dfregval = pd.DataFrame()
            with z.open(name) as etest_zip:
                for head_site, loclist in zip(head_siteparam_tup_list, linesineed):  #is there a way to turn this all into a function inside a list comprehension?
                    regvals_ext = [x for x in loclist if pattern.search(x)]
                    #print(regvals_ext)
                    regvaltups_list = [tuple(x.split(":")[0:2]) for x in regvals_ext]
                    
                    regvaldict = dict(regvaltups_list)
                    regvaltupaggr_list.append(regvaldict)
                    head_siteloc_tup = (head_site[1], head_site[0].split(',')[0], head_site[0].split(',')[1])
                    # print(head_siteloc_tup)
                    head_sitetupaggr_list.append(head_siteloc_tup)

                #print(head_sitetupaggr_list)
                head_site_df = pd.DataFrame(head_sitetupaggr_list, columns =['Die Loc', 'X Coord', 'Y Coord'])
                regvalfile_df = pd.DataFrame(regvaltupaggr_list)
```

Comment: Can you provide a smaller example? Or at least show the dataframes you want to combine?

Comment: So i showed that whole code so that you can trace where the dataframes come from. But I will edit it to show exclusively the two dataframes @cmosig

Comment: Few people have time to read all of your code ;)

Comment: @cmosig I just edited it to show the two DFs right at the top

Comment: @cmosig edited to make it shorter

Comment: That does not tell one much how the dataframes look, e.g., which columns are present. If you just want to slap two dataframes next to each other than you can use `pd.concat([dfs], axis=1)`.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. If performance is what you're after and you're using OS X or some Linux, export your tables to tab-delimited text and use `cut`, `paste`, and process substitutions to join the columns you want from each file.

Comment: @cmosig Check again the top code snippet that contains the two dataframes. The first DF has columns: 'Die Loc', 'X Coord', 'Y Coord', the second has a lot of columns that come from the log files themselves. Way too much to be written out here. They are ppulled from values within the log files. How do you combine one DF with same amount of rows but much less columns to another that has a large amount of columns.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Performance is what I am after. I know those 4 Pandas methods can do sort of what I am looking for, I just don't know which one is most efficient. I am working in a Windows server environment

Comment: @edo101 I think you are asking for `pd.concat([dfs], axis=1)`. A minimal example would help.

Comment: @cmosig what do you mean by minimal example? The example output I want is the excel sheet. I want to take those two DFs and combine them to make the headers and rows of that excel sheet i put in as a picture.

Comment: @cmosig I have made more edits to the OP for hopefully better clarity

Comment: If performance is what you're after, then Python is the wrong tool for this job. I'm not trying to be glib here, it's just that this is not Python's strength.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Ha no offense taken. What would your recommend so I can bring it to my team. THey're the ones that decide on Python long before I joined.

Comment: @cmosig the concat works. I guess Ill test out the other methods and see what's the fastest